# QTreeView How to change vertical scroll bar styles(shape and color etc)?

Tags: qt

Could you pls tell me for class QTreeView How to change vertical scroll bar styles(shape and color etc) through coding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set stylesheet for your scroll bar, for example:

```
myQTreeView->verticalScrollBar()->setStyleSheet(
    "background-color: #EAF5FF;"
    "alternate-background-color: #D5EAFF;"
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Here I dint see setStylesheet function myQTreeView->verticalScrollBar() after this.

Comment: So you forgot to include QScrollBar (#include <qscrollbar.h>)

Comment: You can find examples for styling your scroll bars here in the doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-8e7e0fb0-d01e-4860-8324-19a820a7177c